# How to remove _id from MongoDB results?

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I am inserting json file into Mongodb(with Scala/Play framework) and the same getting/downloading it into my view page for some other requirement, but this time it is coming with one "`_id`" parameter in the json file.

But I need only my actual json file only that is not having any any "`_id`" parameter. I have read the Mongodb tutorial, that by default storing it with one _id for any collection document.

Please let me know that how can I get or is there any chance to get my actual json file without any `_id` in MongoDB.

this is the json result which is storing in database(I don't need that "_id" parameter)

```
{
        "testjson": [{
        "key01": "value1",
        "key02": "value02",
        "key03": "value03"
    }],
  "_id": 1
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at [ReactiveMongo dev guide](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/find-documents.html) and to its [API](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericCollection@find[S,P](selector:S,projection:P)(implicitswriter:GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer[S],implicitpwriter:GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer[P]):reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericQueryBuilder[GenericCollection.this.pack.type]), you can see it support projection in a [similar way as the MongoDB shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

Then you can understand that you can do

```
collection.find(selector = BSONDocument(), projection = BSONDocument("_id" -> 0))
```

Or, as you are using [JSON serialization](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/json/overview.html):

```
collection.find(selector = Json.obj(), projection = Json.obj("_id" -> 0))
```

Comment: thanks you for your reply, I have added as per your comment, but this time also I can see  _id is appended in my json. Edited the above query in description

Comment: I have added the same thing at one more place in my other file, now it is working fine now. Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query in the shell:

```
db.testtable.find({},{"_id" : false})
```

Here we are telling mongoDB not to return `_id` from the collection. 
You can also use `0` instead of false, like this:

```
db.testtable.find({},{"_id" : 0})
```

for scala you need to convert it in as per the driver syntax.

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes it is giving without any _id from the collection if I run it on my shell console. But I am not sure how can I apply it in scala.

Comment: Just find it in documentation. Isn't it there?

Comment: yeah, I am checking in Play/Scala documentation, but I couldn't find.